# Considering ordered populations and different population elements in genetic algorithms

Tags: python, machine-learning, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

I am currently working with neural networks and I would like to start incorporating genetic algorithms (GA) to my problem. I was thinking of considering each layer as an individual in the population. However, to do so, I have to consider the order of the layers (apart from each layer's individual genome).

Additionally, I have to consider different population elements (i.e. a convolutional layer will have a completely distinct set of parameters from a fully connected layer).

Is there a general framework for this? I am currently using Python 3.6, if it helps. I have read some papers on this subject (i.e. [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.00764.pdf) and [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.01563.pdf)) and tried to get ahold of some neuro-evolution material, but I cannot understand how a general GA works with order and different population elements.

If possible I would also greatly appreciate some reading material on this subject.

Comment: Tensorflow works great for neural networks and you can implement GA quite easily through there. I.E [this](https://blog.coast.ai/lets-evolve-a-neural-network-with-a-genetic-algorithm-code-included-8809bece164)

Comment: Why do you want to use layers as individuals, instead of the whole network? If it helps, https://neuralfit.net/ allows you to evolve network (architectures) in Python.

Comment: @ThomasWagenaar I did not say I wanted to use layers as individuals, I was enumerating my lack of understanding regarding the construction of a genotype. And yes, **now** these frameworks are abundantly available :-) at the time of the question this wasn't the case